# MATLAB: Scatter plot with conditional coloring

Tags: matlab

I have a large `data` matrix with 5 columns. 5th column contains many zeros. I want to do `scatter(data(:,4),data(:,5))` and set a different color for points/rows where value in 5th column is zero.

I will then draw scatter plot of different columns but with same condition i.e. different color where values in 5th column are zeros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily set the different color-flag as a fourth parameter in a function:

```
scatter(d(:,4), d(:,5), 7, d(:,5)==0);
```

Here `d(:,4)` and `d(:,5)` are the coordinates of points, `7` is the size of the point, and `d(:,5)==0` is the color-flag (for different values of `d(:,5)`, different colors are chosen).

Comment: No, I didn't ask for this. It colors the plot like a vertical gradient. While It should color the specific points in different color only

Comment: Sorry, I thought you have only zeros and ones in the last column. Anyway, I am glad it helped!